# simplejson - encoding regexp \d+

Tags: python, simplejson

I have some missunderstanding with encoding regexp:

```
>>> simplejson.dumps({'title':r'\d+'})
'{"title": "\\\\d+"}'
>>> simplejson.loads('{"title": "\\\\d+"}')
{u'title': u'\\d+'}
>>> print simplejson.loads('{"title": "\\\\d+"}')['title']
\d+
```

So, without using `print` I see `\\`, with using `print` I see `\`. So, what the value loaded dict contains - with `\\` or with `\`?

Comment: `r''` is a raw string literal, not a regular expression. Such literals are useful and helpful when creating a regular expression, but they are a separate concept altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a trick: Use `list` to see what characters are really in the string:

```
In [3]: list(u'\\d+')
Out[3]: [u'\\', u'd', u'+']
```

`list` breaks up the string into individual characters. So `u'\\'` is one character. (The double backslash in `u'\\'` is an [escape sequence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html).) It represents one backslash character.  This is correct since `r'\d+'` also has only one backslash:

```
In [4]: list(r'\d+')
Out[4]: ['\\', 'd', '+']
```